# ¿Cómo crear un trigger que sume un tipo INT a un tipo DATE en phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

En este problema creo una credencial para un empleado de mi tabla 'empleados' la cual tiene una fecha de emisión (f_emision) y debe tener una fecha de vigencia (f_vigencia) de acuerdo a un número de dias especificado en una tabla de 'control'.

Quisiera crear un trigger que sume el valor entero dentro del campo vigencia (control.dias_vigencia) a mi fecha de emisión cada vez que INSERTO un nuevo empleado y cada vez que lo ACTUALIZO

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para empezar quise probar con una función de MySQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El trigger funciona, pero ahora debo reemplazar ese intervalo por el valor ubicado en mi tabla de control:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo más razonable es que hagas este "trigger" al momento en que haces tu consulta, o antes, es decir, hacer las operaciones pertinentes antes de ejecutar tu consulta en tu código fuente, ya sea antes del INSERT o del UPDATE, desconozco si se puede en phpmyadmin.